# Laravel - Undefined variable $data on view

Tags: php, controller, laravel-5.5

I have a problem with this.

> Undefined variable: acara (View:
>   /var/www/html/event_organizer/resources/views/admin/home.blade.php)

But I have declared $acara on the controller like this

**Controller**

```
use App\events; 

    public function lihat_acara()
    {
      $data['acara'] = events::all();
      return view('admin.home')->with($data);
    }
```

and the view like this

**home.blade.php**

```
@foreach($acara as $key)
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $key->nama_acara }}</td>
      <td>{{ $key->kategori_acara }}</td>
      <td>{{ $key->lokasi_acara }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  @endforeach
```

What's wrong with my code? Any idea? :)

Comment: Controller: `view('admin.home', compact("data"));`. In your home.blade.php, `@foreach($data["acara"] as $key)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use App\events; 

public function lihat_acara()
{
  $data['acara'] = events::all();
  return view('admin.home', ['acara' => $data['acara'] ]);
}
```

OR

```
use App\events; 

public function lihat_acara()
{
  $data['acara'] = events::all();
  return view('admin.home')->with('acara', $data['acara']);
}
```

OR

```
use App\events; 

public function lihat_acara()
{
  $data['acara'] = events::all();
  return view('admin.home')->withAcara($data['acara']);
}
```

From this laravel official site [Passing data to view](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views), you can find all the way to send data from controller to view.

Comment: yeah, of course, please see 1st case. that will give the array.
you changed your answer format like me. :)

Comment: hmm... I think you need to read the official document again. first case data is second parameter of view function.
second case, view('viewname')->with('variablename', value).
that's not the same type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166728/discussion-between-hkg328-and-rahul-shrivastava).

Comment: Yeah, thanks :). I've try your suggestion and it work too

Answer (score 4):

You need to change `with()` it's take an array

Change

```
with(['data'=>$data]);
```

or you can do like this also

```
withData($data);
```

Now you can receive the variable in view with `$data`  and
in your case it will be

```
use App\events; 

    public function lihat_acara()
    {
      $data['acara'] = events::all();
      return view('admin.home')->with(['acara'=>$data['acara']]);
    }
```

Or

```
use App\events; 

    public function lihat_acara()
    {
      $data['acara'] = events::all();
      return view('admin.home')->withAcara($data['acara']);
    }
```

Comment: we need to pass variable and value(two parameters) into with() function.
or you can pass the array of variables as second parameter of view() function

Comment: you've updated your answer several time along my answer. and why did you remove all comment you wrote to my answer?

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario above, the `acara` is not a variable you declared `acara` as an array key. I don't know why you had to do it like this. You can simply write the code like this:

```
$acara = Event::all();
```

**OR**

If you want to keep the controller like that, change the variable in `@foreach` loop:

```
@foreach($data['acara'] as $key)
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $key->nama_acara }}</td>
        <td>{{ $key->kategori_acara }}</td>
        <td>{{ $key->lokasi_acara }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
@endforeach
```