# $home is undefined when trying to fetch data

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to fetch data from my admin_homes table, here is what my controller looks like:

```
public function index()
{
    $home = AdminHome::all();
    return view('admin.home.index', compact('home'));
}
```

I use foreach ($home as $homes) in my blade view but when I run it, I get an error saying "$home is undefined". How to solve this?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49248709/laravel-undefined-variable-data-on-view

Comment: No problem Happy coding 

Comment: I got another problem. The admin.home.index is the landing page for admin user and I get same error everytime I log in with admin user. But it works just fine when I write down the URL manually. @BeshambherChaukhwan

Comment: Must be some issue with the session. Check the post login flow. The controller is simple so manual routing is not showing error.